# Cannot find database in server 2 laravel 5.3

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have mysql running using WAMP. I have created my database on this server below is the screenshot:
[image: 5.]

So database is exist there. And here's my env file :
[image]
config file:
[image]

So env file here is ok. but when I open my laravel, I found this error:
[image]

So what's wrong here? Is it related to `server=2` in my phpMyAdmin?
Thank you

Comment: Can you use the mysql CLI to check the databases? Use the `show databases` command to make sure it's not phpmyadmin issue

Comment: Also your mysql points to 3308 if you have a look at the first screenshot, thus try modifying the port to 3308 instead of 3306.

Comment: @SachinBahukhandi. yess... the port is different. I didn't realize it. Now it's working w. Thanks for your time mr. Sachin :)

Comment: Sure. I will post it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in case anyone faces the issue go for every detail in the `.env` file.

Also, the first screenshot points out to the port **3308** but in `.env` file the

```
DB_PORT= 3306
```

Which should be set to:

```
DB_PORT=3308
```

Hope this helps. Thank you.